# php + jqgrid + export to excel

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

Somebody knows a way to export the data from a jqgrid to excel?

I want to do a report using this jqgrid that i think is  awsome. But i need to save or print this report somehow, because is information to be keeped.
Somebody knows any way??

Answer (score 12):

This is my approach, just add this code to your js/html file

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',{view:true, del:false, add:false, edit:false, excel:true})
                .navButtonAdd('#pager',{
                                caption:"Export to Excel", 
                                buttonicon:"ui-icon-save", 
                                onClickButton: function(){ 
                                  exportExcel();
                                }, 
                                position:"last"
                            });

        function exportExcel()
        {
            var mya=new Array();
            mya=$("#list").getDataIDs();  // Get All IDs
            var data=$("#list").getRowData(mya[0]);     // Get First row to get the labels
            var colNames=new Array(); 
            var ii=0;
            for (var i in data){colNames[ii++]=i;}    // capture col names
            var html="";
            for(i=0;i<mya.length;i++)
                {
                data=$("#list").getRowData(mya[i]); // get each row
                for(j=0;j<colNames.length;j++)
                    {
                    html=html+data[colNames[j]]+"\t"; // output each column as tab delimited
                    }
                html=html+"\n";  // output each row with end of line

                }
            html=html+"\n";  // end of line at the end
            document.forms[0].csvBuffer.value=html;
            document.forms[0].method='POST';
            document.forms[0].action='csvExport.php';  // send it to server which will open this contents in excel file
            document.forms[0].target='_blank';
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
```

PHP script

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$buffer = $_POST['csvBuffer'];

try{
    echo $buffer;
}catch(Exception $e){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for share your code Felix Guerrero. I have a problem: when I run your code I get this error: document.forms[0].csvBuffer is undefined, can you help me to fix this?

Comment: This code does appear to consider only visible rows, have you any hint on how to get the full list (i.e. not only the rows in current page)?

Comment: Thanks Felix  ,i used this example with jspdf and it was very usefull, thaks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

very good question, i was scratching my head off about this as well.
I made it by choosing Felix's suggestion, let me complete it by adding following lines to your
html body.

```
<form method="post" action="csvExport.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="csvBuffer" id="csvBuffer" value="" />
</form>
```

The only problem i have is the excel file exported doesnt include my column names in jqgrid, also is there a way to exclude a particular or several columns when exporting to excel file?

thank you ~

Answer (score 3):

Here is a clever solution to save the `jqGrid` data as excel sheet without calling the `php` script: (You just need to call this function with `GridID` and an optional `Filename`)

```
var createExcelFromGrid = function(gridID,filename) {
    var grid = $('#' + gridID);
    var rowIDList = grid.getDataIDs();
    var row = grid.getRowData(rowIDList[0]); 
    var colNames = [];
    var i = 0;
    for(var cName in row) {
        colNames[i++] = cName; // Capture Column Names
    }
    var html = "";
    for(var j=0;j<rowIDList.length;j++) {
        row = grid.getRowData(rowIDList[j]); // Get Each Row
        for(var i = 0 ; i<colNames.length ; i++ ) {
            html += row[colNames[i]] + ';'; // Create a CSV delimited with ;
        }
        html += '\n';
    }
    html += '\n';

    var a         = document.createElement('a');
    a.id = 'ExcelDL';
    a.href        = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + html;
    a.download    = filename ? filename + ".xls" : 'DataList.xls';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click(); // Downloads the excel document
    document.getElementById('ExcelDL').remove();
}
```

We first create a `CSV` string delimited with `;`. Then an `anchor` tag is created with certain attributes. Finally `click` is called on `a` to download the file.

You could have a look at several excel MIME Types : [MIME Type List](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Answer (score 2):

Great function!
I have made changes.

```
function exportExcel($id){
  var keys=[], ii=0, rows="";
  var ids=$id.getDataIDs();  // Get All IDs
  var row=$id.getRowData(ids[0]);     // Get First row to get the labels
  for (var k in row) {
    keys[ii++]=k;    // capture col names
    rows=rows+k+"\t";     // output each Column as tab delimited
  }
  rows=rows+"\n";   // Output header with end of line
  for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
    row=$id.getRowData(ids[i]); // get each row
    for(j=0;j<keys.length;j++) rows=rows+row[keys[j]]+"\t"; // output each Row as tab delimited
    rows=rows+"\n";  // output each row with end of line
  }
  rows=rows+"\n";  // end of line at the end
  var form = "<form name='csvexportform' action='"+php_path+"csvexport.php' method='post'>";
  form = form + "<input type='hidden' name='csvBuffer' value='"+rows+"'>";
  form = form + "</form><script>document.csvexportform.submit();</sc"+"ript>";
  OpenWindow=window.open('', '');
  OpenWindow.document.write(form);
  OpenWindow.document.close();
}

function gridcsvexport(id) {
  $('#'+id).jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#'+id+'_pager',{
    caption:'',
    title:'export',
    buttonicon:'ui-icon-newwin',
    position:'last',
    onClickButton:function (){
      exportExcel($(this));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem .and now iam able to export data excel with column names please refer my code.

```
function exportExcel()
    {
        var mya=new Array();
        mya=$("#tblnoupdate").getDataIDs();  // Get All IDs
        var data=$("#tblnoupdate").getRowData(mya[0]);     // Get First row to get the labels
        var colNames=new Array(); 
        var ii=0;
        for (var i in data){colNames[ii++]=i;}    // capture col names
        var html="";
            for(k=0;k<colNames.length;k++)
            {
            html=html+colNames[k]+"\t";     // output each Column as tab delimited
            }
            html=html+"\n";                    // Output header with end of line
        for(i=0;i<mya.length;i++)
            {
            data=$("#tblnoupdate").getRowData(mya[i]); // get each row
            for(j=0;j<colNames.length;j++)
                {
             html=html+data[colNames[j]]+"\t"; // output each Row as tab delimited
                }
            html=html+"\n";  // output each row with end of line

            }
        html=html+"\n";  // end of line at the end
        document.forms[0].csvBuffer.value=html;
        document.forms[0].method='POST';
        document.forms[0].action='<?php echo $baseurl;?>csvexport.php';  // send it to server which will open this contents in excel file
        document.forms[0].target='_blank';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

Please let me know if you face  any problem.

Answer (score 0):

create a form and a hidden element with the name "csvBuffer". This element gets set by the function.
I had to change the line

```
html = html+"\n"
```

to

```
html = html+"\\n"
```

in order to escape it properly.