# How to export jqgrid to excel?

Tags: jquery, grails, jqgrid, export-to-excel

I am having jquery's jqgrid where in the User can filter the grid data and export the filtered data to excel.

I'm trying to implement in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188762/php-jqgrid-export-to-excel) way. But mine is not a PHP but Grails application. The application will be deployed in Tomcat. How can I write similar thing in GSP/JSP?

Or is there any better way to **export the filtered jqgrid to EXCEL**?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the export plugin in Grails. 
Refer:  http://www.grails.org/plugin/export